# Bubble sort algorithm JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, bubble-sort

Please can you tell me what is wrong to this implementation of bubble sort algorithm in JavaScript?

```
for (var i=1; i<records.length; i++){
        for (var j=records.length; j<1; j--){
            if (parseInt(records[i-1]) < parseInt(records[i])){
                var temp = records[i-1];
                records[i-1] = records[i]
                records[i] = temp;
            }   
        }    
    }
```

Comment: This might work better if you tell ***us*** what the ***problem*** is with it, and then we might be able to tell your how to fix it.

Comment: these posts are regrettable, their writing does not respect the original algorithm.

Answer (score 37):

Couple of codes for bubble sort

bubblesort should not be used for larger arrays, can be used for smaller ones for its simplicity.

**Optimized way, with all Checks**

```js
const bubble_Sort = (nums) => {
  if(!Array.isArray(nums)) return -1; // --->if passed argument is not array
  if(nums.length<2) return nums; // --->if array length is one or less

    let swapped=false
     temp=0,
     count=-1,
     arrLength=0;


    do{
      count ++;
      swapped=false;
      arrLength = (nums.length-1) - count; //---> not loop through sorted items
      for(let i=0; i<=arrLength; i++){
          if(nums[i]>nums[i+1]){
            temp=nums[i+1];
            nums[i+1]=nums[i];
            nums[i]=temp;
            swapped=true;
          }
      }
    }

    while(swapped)
    return nums;
  }
  console.log(bubble_Sort([3, 0, 2, 5, -1, 4, 1]));
```

**Method 1**

```js
var a = [33, 103, 3, 726, 200, 984, 198, 764, 9];

function bubbleSort(a) {
    var swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                var temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
}

bubbleSort(a);
console.log(a);
```

**Method 2**

```js
function bubbleSort(items) {
    var length = items.length;
    //Number of passes
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        //Notice that j < (length - i)
        for (var j = 0; j < (length - i - 1); j++) { 
            //Compare the adjacent positions
            if(items[j] > items[j+1]) {
                //Swap the numbers
                var tmp = items[j];  //Temporary variable to hold the current number
                items[j] = items[j+1]; //Replace current number with adjacent number
                items[j+1] = tmp; //Replace adjacent number with current number
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

**Method 3**

```js
function bubbleSort() {
    var numElements = this.dataStore.length;
    var temp;
    for (var outer = numElements; outer >= 2; --outer) {
        for (var inner = 0; inner <= outer-1; ++inner) {
            if (this.dataStore[inner] > this.dataStore[inner+1]) {
                swap(this.dataStore, inner, inner+1); }
        }
        console.log(this.toString()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Method 3 is error & partly codes! `this.dataStore.length` what's that mean ?[error codes](https://repl.it/Ev0O/1)

Comment: In Method 1 , after each phase of swapping , bigger numbers always bubbles to right , so in the second phase , we can ignore the the last element , similarly after each phase we can reduce the size the array to be looked by 1 . This will reduce no of comparisons:

Comment: `function bubbleSort(a) {
    var swapped, len = a.length;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                var temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        } len--
    } while (swapped);
}
bubbleSort(a);`

Comment: Optimized way rejects TypedArray (would return -1) although the algo would work with a TypedArray.

Comment: In the Optimized solution, it should be `i<arrLength` instead of `i<=arrLength`.

Comment: these posts are regrettable, their writing does not respect the original algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (var j=records.length; j<1; j--){
```

Shouldn't that be

```
for (var j=records.length; j>1; j--){
```

Comment: i think it should be (records.length - 1) as the index start from 0

Comment: But j isn't used as an index into an array; rather it is used as a counter

Comment: is that really a bubble sort ? how will that work ??

Comment: It won't bubble sort at the moment - it will just keep swapping the i and (i - 1)th element. I was just pointing out the obvious problem with his code (the reason the inner loop wasn't being entered).

Comment: yeah i was pointing that too :)

Comment: Yes, it is. Bubble sort - exchange neihgbour items if they are not in correct order. For array with length N you need to repeat this N-1 times. There are a lot of optimization/modifications of it. The best is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_sort Shell sort

Comment: In its broken state it wasn't a bubble sort is what I meant. He wasn't indexing his records array with the correct variable. It looked like a bit of a 'homework' question so I provided the syntax correction in the hope it might help him to debug it

Answer (score 3):

A simple implementation in ES6 JavaScript will be

```js
    function BubbleSort(arr) {
      const sortedArray = Array.from(arr);
      let swap;
      do {
        swap = false;
        for (let i = 1; i < sortedArray.length; ++i) {
          if (sortedArray[i - 1] > sortedArray[i]) {
            [sortedArray[i], sortedArray[i - 1]] = [sortedArray[i - 1], sortedArray[i]];
            swap = true;
          }
        }
      } while (swap)
      return sortedArray;
    }
console.log(BubbleSort([3, 12, 9, 5]));
```

Comment: these posts are regrettable, their writing does not respect the original algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

you should use j instead of i in the second loop, and don't forget to change the j<1 to j>1

Comment: Well thank you, i think i use J instead of I

Comment: `if (parseInt(records[i-1]) < parseInt(records[i])){
                var temp = records[i-1];
                records[i-1] = records[i]
                records[i] = temp;`
that's i there

Comment: Yes you are right, but then i get: TypeError: records[j] is undefined

Comment: that's because you are trying to access records[records.length], which doesn't exist in this array, if you want to start the for loop from the end, you have to start with records.length-1 `for (var j=records.length-1; j>0; j--) `

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in a bubble sort, once the i loop has completed an iteration, then the i'th element is now in its correct position.  That means that you should write the j loop as

```
for (var j = i + 1; j < records.length; j++)
```

Otherwise your bubble sort will be (even more) inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
  function bubbleSort(A){
  var swapped,
      len = arr.length;

  if(len === 1) return;

  do {
    swapped = false;
    for(var i=1;i<len;i++) {
      if(A[i-1] > A[i]) {   
        var b = A[i];
        A[i] = A[i-1];
        A[i-1] = b;
        swapped = true;
      }   
    }

  }
  while(swapped)  
}

var arr = [1, 6, 9, 5, 3, 4, 2, 12, 4567, 5, 34];
bubbleSort(arr);
document.write(arr);
```

Comment: these posts are regrettable, their writing does not respect the original algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

the second `for` loop is coded wrong it should be

```
for (var i=0; i<records.length; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<records.length; j++){
        if (parseInt(records[i]) > parseInt(records[j])){
            var temp = records[i];
            records[i] = records[j];
            records[j] = temp;
        }   
    }    
}
```

Comment: It is better to nest your `for` loop inside a `while` loop and establish a predicate for looping. The code above will continue looping and looping, till it ends... even once the list elements have already been placed in order.

Comment: I think your code works O(n2) when best case also at place. it costly to have like this code. according to this situation its not quite well. stick to the complexity also

Comment: these posts are regrettable, their writing does not respect the original algorithm.