# I keep getting cannot read property error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a bubblesort. I am using this algorithm to sort a 2d array and I keep getting an error. Here is the function:

```
var array = [
    [ "Rober Hill"         , 123.54  ],
    [ "Chrsitopher Reddkin", 54.67   ],
    [ "Maggie Woods"       , 1000.87 ],
    [ "Jennifer Jones"     , 3.34    ],
    [ "Marcus Parker"      , 64.98   ]
];
table = document.getElementById("table");

function bubbleSort(array, length, element) 
{
    var swapped = false;
    do 
    {
        for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++) // Line 59
        {
            if (array[a][1] > array[a+1][1])
            {
                var temp = array[a][1];
                array[a][1] = array[a+1][1];
                array[a+1][1] = temp; 
                swapped = true; 
            }
        }
    } while(swapped);

    return array;

}
```

The error says: `Sorting.html:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. I have this function on a button. Any kind of help would be nice! Thank you

Comment: Which is line 59?

Comment: line 59: for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++)

Comment: Possible for you to create a working demo for myself and others to work with?

Comment: Maybe this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/Lx1fun0b/) might be of some help. I don't know what you want to order them by but credit to [**This Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502489/bubble-sort-algorithm-javascript/#answer-37901176) for the function source code used in my example.

Comment: I doubt very much that is line 59. The error messages in the console are typically clickable and will take you directly to the source code.

Comment: Also, how **exactly** are you calling `bubbleSort()`? What arguments are you providing for the `array`, `length` and `element` parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Running your code exactly as it is, I get:

`Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

This is because in your comparison, you're attempting to compare `array[a][1] > array[a+1][1]`, and this works except for the last loop, where `array[a+1]` doesn't exist, and because it doesn't exist, 1 is undefined.

Here's a working solution, with a few notable differences.

1. I don't know why you had `length`, and `element` as parameters for your `bubbleSort`, but they're gone now
2. You can just use the array length in your for loop, that way if you add more items to your array, you don't have to update the `5` you had hardcoded.
3. In the `for` loop, I minus 1 from the array length so we're never trying to compare the last item against an item after it that doesn't exist.
4. Also, I used `i` instead of `a`, since that's a common variable name for an incrementer.
5. I defined `swapped` inside the `do...while`, otherwise you'll have created an infinite loop because `swapped` will get set to `true` on the first pass and stay `true` forever.
6. You don't have to return the array, as it is modifying the original in place when you call `bubbleSort`

```js
var array = [
  ["Rober Hill", 123.54],
  ["Chrsitopher Reddkin", 54.67],
  ["Maggie Woods", 1000.87],
  ["Jennifer Jones", 3.34],
  ["Marcus Parker", 64.98]
];

function bubbleSort(array) {
  do {
    var swapped = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
      if (array[i][1] > array[i + 1][1]) {
        var temp = array[i];

        array[i] = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = temp;

        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
}

bubbleSort(array)
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `var swapped = false;` inside `do {...`.

Also update condition in `for` it should be like `a < 4;` or it's better if you use generalized condition as `a < array.length - 1;`

```js
var array = [
  ["Rober Hill", 123.54],
  ["Chrsitopher Reddkin", 54.67],
  ["Maggie Woods", 1000.87],
  ["Jennifer Jones", 3.34],
  ["Marcus Parker", 64.98]
];

function bubbleSort(array, length, element) {
  do {
    var swapped = false;
    for (var a = 0; a < array.length - 1; a++) // Line 59
    {
      if (array[a][1] > array[a + 1][1]) {
        var temp = array[a][1];
        array[a][1] = array[a + 1][1];
        array[a + 1][1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);

  return array;

}

console.log(bubbleSort(array));
```