# in the easiest and most concise way as possible

Tags: javascript, methods

I want to sort an array values in an ascending or descending order without using sort().

I have created a function, however I am not satisfied with it. 
I believe the code below could be much shorter and more concise.

Please let me know where to modify or you may entirely change the code too. Thank you in advance.

```
const func = arg => {
    let flip = false;
    let copy = [];

    for(let val of arg) copy[copy.length] = val;    
    for(let i=0; i<arg.length; i++) {
        const previous = arg[i-1];
        const current = arg[i];

        if(previous > current) {
            flip = true;
            copy[i] = previous;
            copy[i-1] = current;
        }
    }

    if(flip) return func(copy);
    return copy;
};

l(func([5,2,8,1,9,4,7,3,6]));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901176/10221765

Comment: It's not clear what your goals are here. It sounds like you want shorter code; most people want more efficient code. This is current and n^2 algorithm. So it could definitely be more efficient.

Comment: Please edit the title to reflect something more specific to your issue.

Comment: Can you talk us through why you don't want to use `sort`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is composed of whole numbers, as in the example, pne option is to reduce the array into an object, whose keys are the numbers, and whose values are the number of times those values have occured so far. Then, iterate over the object (whose `Object.entries` will iterate in *ascending numeric key order*, for whole number keys), and create the array to return:

```js
const func = arr => {
  const valuesObj = {};
  arr.forEach((num) => {
    valuesObj[num] = (valuesObj[num] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return Object.entries(valuesObj)
    .flatMap(
      ([num, count]) => Array(count).fill(num)
    );
};


console.log(
  func([5,2,8,1,9,10,10,11,4,7,3,6])
);
```

This runs in `O(N)` time.

To account for negative integers as well while keeping `O(N)` runtime, create another object for negatives:

```js
const func = arr => {
  const valuesObj = {};
  const negativeValuesObj = {};
  arr.forEach((num) => {
    if (num >= 0) valuesObj[num] = (valuesObj[num] || 0) + 1;
    else negativeValuesObj[-num] = (negativeValuesObj[-num] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return [
    ...Object.entries(negativeValuesObj).reverse()
      .flatMap(
        ([num, count]) => Array(count).fill(-num)
      ),
    ...Object.entries(valuesObj)
      .flatMap(
        ([num, count]) => Array(count).fill(num)
      )
  ];
};


console.log(
  func([5,2,8,1,-5, -1, 9,10,10,11,4,7,3,6, -10])
);
```

For non-integer items, you'll have to use a different algorithm with higher computational complexity.

Comment: Should probably be `integer keys` — "numeric keys" would suggest it includes floats.